# Starting multiple processes inside a function makes it loop for each process started

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm writing a program and made a "pseudo" program which imitates same thing as the main one does. The main idea is that a program starts and it scans a game. First part detects if game started, then it open 2 processes. 1 that scans the game all the time and sends info to the second process, which analyzes the data and plots it. In short, its 2 infinite loops running simultaneously.

I'm trying to put it all into functions now so I can run it through `tkinter` and make a GUI for it.

The issue is, every time a process starts, it loops back on start of parent function, executes it again, then goes to start second process. What is the issue here? In this test model, one process sends value of X to second process which prints it out.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Pipe


def function_start():
    print("GAME DETECTED AND STARTED")
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_first_process_loop, args=(child_conn,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_second_process_loop, args=(parent_conn,))
    function_load(p1)
    function_load(p2)

def function_load(process):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("slept 1")
        process.start()




def function_first_process_loop(conn):
    x=0
    print("FIRST PROCESS STARTED")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        x += 1
        conn.send(x)
        print(x)


def function_second_process_loop(conn):
    print("SECOND PROCESS STARTED")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv()
        print(data)

function_start()
```

I've also tried rearranging functions a bit on different ways. This is one of them:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Pipe


def function_load():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_first_process_loop, args=(child_conn,))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_second_process_loop, args=(parent_conn,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()

#FIRST
def function_start():
    print("GAME LOADED AND STARTED")
    function_load()




def function_first_process_loop(conn):
    x=0
    print("FIRST PROCESS STARTED")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        x += 1
        conn.send(x)
        print(x)


def function_second_process_loop(conn):
    print("SECOND PROCESS STARTED")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv()
        print(data)

#



function_start()
```

Comment: Enclose the call to `function_start()` in `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always tag your question tagged with `multiprocessing` with platform you are running under, but I will infer that it is probably Windows or some other platform that uses the *spawn* method to launch new processes. That means when a new process is created, a new Python interpreter is launched an the program source is processed from the top and any code at global scope that is not protected by the check `if __name__ == '__main__':` will be executed, which means that each started process will be executing the statement `function_start()`.

So, as @PranavHosangadi rightly pointed out you need the `__name__` check in the correct place.

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pipe
import time

def function_start():
    print("GAME DETECTED AND STARTED")
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_first_process_loop, args=(child_conn,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_second_process_loop, args=(parent_conn,))
    function_load(p1)
    function_load(p2)

def function_load(process):
    print("slept 1")
    process.start()




def function_first_process_loop(conn):
    x=0
    print("FIRST PROCESS STARTED")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        x += 1
        conn.send(x)
        print(x)


def function_second_process_loop(conn):
    print("SECOND PROCESS STARTED")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv()
        print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function_start()
```

Comment: This explains it all. Thank you alot!  Btw i did read minimal code guidelines and i though i did comply my code with it. I just posted 2 different variations of the same problem. I dont know exactly where i failed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do an experiment: Before `function_start()`, add this line:

```
print(__name__, "calling function_start()")
```

Now, you get the following output:

```
__main__ calling function_start()
GAME DETECTED AND STARTED
slept 1
slept 1
__mp_main__ calling function_start()
GAME DETECTED AND STARTED
__mp_main__ calling function_start()
GAME DETECTED AND STARTED
FIRST PROCESS STARTED
SECOND PROCESS STARTED
1
1
2
2
...
```

Clearly, `function_start()` is called by the child process every time you start it. This is because python loads the entire script, and then calls the function you want from that script. The new processes have the name `__mp_main__` to differentiate them from the main process, and you can make use of that to prevent the call to `function_start()` by these processes.

So instead of `function_start()`, call it this way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(__name__, "calling function_start()")
    function_start()
```

and now you get what you wanted:

```
__main__ calling function_start()
GAME DETECTED AND STARTED
slept 1
slept 1
FIRST PROCESS STARTED
SECOND PROCESS STARTED
1
1
2
2
...
```

Comment: Thank you alot!  I kinda missed the part of what the main and name part is actually for, just went with it.